# Broadband gets connected but can't browse anything further google!

Tags: 12.10, networking

I have a dell inspiron 3520 with ubuntu 12.10 installed. My BSNL broadband gets connected(both wired and wireless) but I haven't been able to access anything except google. Same problem I had with xubuntu 13.04 before I installed ubuntu 12.10. Broadband works fine on windows 7. Please help.

Comment: Maybe google.com is saved at your browser's cache and you can't browse it either? Try hitting refresh and tell me what happens.

Comment: I can search stuff on google and get results...

Comment: But you cannot access other websites, right?

Comment: yes, not even facebook or wiki!

Comment: when you try to access anything except google you get "waiting for..." and finally the connection cannot be established?

Comment: Please add the error that you get while opening other sites.

Comment: I don't get any errors, any prompts. It just goes on and on...

Comment: It doesn't say anything like "Server took too long to respond" or "DNS lookup failed" just an infinitive "Connecting..." Status?

Comment: let me check again.

Comment: Interesting. You can search anything on Google, even if you haven't searched it before? But you can't open up any other website? Also, you say the broadband works fine on Windows 7. Is this Windows 7 dual-booting on the same machine, or is it another machine? In a terminal, can you do the commands `ping -c4 4.2.2.2` and `telnet facebook.com 80`, and [edit your answer](http://askubuntu.com/posts/310950/edit) to include the output? (If the terminal is stuck after that second command, hit Ctrl+C a couple of times.)

Comment: I'm not sure what it caused, but resetted every setting in my modem and totally reconfigured it using my Ubuntu laptop. Now it is working fine on both Ubuntu and Windows!

Comment: It's impossible for me to understand why this question has been closed...

Comment: did it solved??? i have also the exact same problem(ie working fine on win7 but able to browse only google,youtube,gmail,.. etc with ubuntu. :(

Comment: i solved it by removing all network connections and then added only the `DSL` connection.

Answer (score 0):

At first, try restarting your router and your computer. It may be possible that your router was reconfigured by windows.

Take a look at the `/etc/resolv.conf`file .

Open **terminal** and enter :

`sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` to open the file.

make sure that you have a line like `nameserver 192.168.2.1` , where 192.168.2.1 is the address of your router.